# In-Memory Lookup in Flink operators

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink application for stream collection and processing. The application consists of Kafka as an event source, a co-map function and a Kafka sink as image shown below:

[image]

I want to enrich the incoming stream from Kafka with some fields from CSV file.
I also want a periodic refresh of the csv file from configured disk location.

Potential Solution : Broadcast the enrichment data and connect with event stream coming from Kafka based on some logic.

Also, reload the data from the file source continuously after a configured interval.

I have below concerns about this design:

1. Is it possible to pause the processing of main stream from Kafka until all data is loaded from File Source using Broadcast Stream.
2. Can there be any better design to implement In-Memory lookup using a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

1. If the enrichment data is joined to the incoming (from Kafka) data using one or more key fields, then you should key the enrichment stream, versus using a broadcast stream.
2. The Flink [FileSource](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/connector/file/src/FileSource.html) can be configured to periodically scan for new files, and start streaming those when found. So that should solve the issue of "periodic refresh".
3. If you're using a `Co(Flat)MapFunction`, then you'll have to take care of saving data in state. You'd do this for the Kafka stream if the enrichment data hasn't arrived yet, and for the CSV stream no matter what.

Having said all of the above, for many use cases leveraging the Flink [Table API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/table/tableapi/) can simplify the amount of code you have to write/debug/maintain.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @kkrugler has proposed, you could load the enrichment data in the `open` method of your enrichment function, and store it in a local variable (rather than in flink state). You could still periodically update it with a broadcast stream, but this would solve the state bootstrapping problem. (Since the ground truth of the state lives in a file, there's no benefit from using Flink state to store this data if you always read it from a file as the job starts.)

One potential problem with pre-loading state in the `open` method is that if you want to have each instance only load the enrichment data for part of the total keyspace, there's no way to anticipate which keys each instance will be handling. You can solve this issue by using a custom partitioner, but then you won't be able to use keyed state.

For more on this topic, see [99 Ways to Enrich Streaming Data with Apache Flink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJS18iKLUIY) and the [corresponding github repo](https://github.com/knaufk/enrichments-with-flink).

Update to address some additional questions in the comments:

1. There is (currently) no way to pause a source so as to wait for another. However, [FLIP-182: Support watermark alignment of FLIP-27 sources](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/x/hQYBCw) will go a long way toward meeting this need. Another possible approach is to bootstrap state using the State Processor API, or to do something with the `HybridSource` (which is really meant for another purpose but might be hacked into a solution to this problem).

2. If two streams from different sources are keyed in compatible ways, so that both streams are mapping their events onto the same key space, then yes, you are guaranteed that all events from both streams with the same key will be sent to the same sub-task. This is the basis for implementing all joins in Flink.
3. A stateless custom partitioner can easily be implemented so that it handles rescaling.
4. Rescaling in Flink (including reactive rescaling) always involves a cluster restart.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kkrugler & David.
David, I have few doubts regarding the approach shared:     
1) Is there any way in flink to pause a source(Kafka source in this case), so that it can wait for the broadcasted stream coming from file source. So that I will not have to load the lookup state in open() method......      
2) if I have 2 streams coming from 2 different sources & both are keyed using the same key. When I receive 1 record from each stream with same value in their keys, will flink always send them to same TM instance?

Adding few more doubts in the next comment

Comment: 3) Can custom partitioner handle state redistribution when a taskmanager is scaled?.....

4) Once the reactive scaling is introduced in flink, how will redistribution of the lookup data work when the taskmanager is scaled up?

Comment: I've expanded my answer to address these points.